# Populating a TextView with a Boolean Value retrieved using a getter method

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, getter-setter

I have developed an Android Application which is connected to a Firebase Database. I'm trying to display some records from a database object in a ListView but I'm not sure how to hand the boolean value. I currently have a GroupVaccinations class which has the Getters for all the info:

```
public class GroupVaccination {
    String vaccinationGroupID;
    String vaccinationGroupNumber;
    String vaccinationID;
    String vaccinationDrug;
    String vaccinationAdmin;
    String vaccinationDosage;
    String vaccinationDate;
    String vaccinationNotes;
    Boolean allVaccinated;

    public GroupVaccination(){

    }

    public GroupVaccination(String vaccinationGroupID, String vaccinationGroupNumber, String vaccinationID, String vaccinationDrug,
                       String vaccinationAdmin, String vaccinationDosage, String vaccinationDate, String vaccinationNotes, Boolean allVaccinated){
        this.vaccinationGroupID = vaccinationGroupID;
        this.vaccinationGroupNumber = vaccinationGroupNumber;
        this.vaccinationID = vaccinationID;
        this.vaccinationDrug = vaccinationDrug;
        this.vaccinationAdmin = vaccinationAdmin;
        this.vaccinationDosage = vaccinationDosage;
        this.vaccinationDate = vaccinationDate;
        this.vaccinationNotes = vaccinationNotes;
        this.allVaccinated = allVaccinated;
    }

    public String getVaccinationGroupID() {   return vaccinationGroupID;    }

    public String getVaccinationGroupNumber() {   return vaccinationGroupNumber;    }

    public String getVaccinationID() {  return vaccinationID;    }

    public String getVaccinationDrug() { return vaccinationDrug; }

    public String getVaccinationAdmin() { return  vaccinationAdmin;}

    public String getVaccinationDosage() {return vaccinationDosage;}

    public String getVaccinationDate() {return  vaccinationDate; }

    public String getVaccinationNotes() {return vaccinationNotes; }

    public Boolean getAllVaccinated() {return allVaccinated; }
```

And I am using an InfoAdapter class to populate the ListView accordingly:

```
public class GroupVaccinationInfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GroupVaccination> {
    private Activity context;
    private List<GroupVaccination> groupVaccinationList;

public GroupVaccinationInfoAdapter(Activity context, List<GroupVaccination>groupVaccinationList){
    super(context, R.layout.group_vaccination_list_view,groupVaccinationList);
    this.context = context;
    this.groupVaccinationList = groupVaccinationList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_vaccination_list_view, null, true);

    TextView vaccinationDrug = (TextView)listView.findViewById(R.id.drug);
    TextView vaccinationDosage = (TextView)listView.findViewById(R.id.dosage);
    TextView vaccinationDate = (TextView)listView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    TextView vaccinationAdmin = (TextView)listView.findViewById(R.id.administrator);
    TextView vaccinationID = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.groupVaccinationID);
    TextView vaccinationGroupNumber = (TextView)listView.findViewById(R.id.groupNumber);
    TextView vaccinationNotes = (TextView)listView.findViewById(R.id.notes);
    TextView allVaccinatedTrueFalse = (TextView)listView.findViewById(R.id.allVaccinatedTrueFalse);



    GroupVaccination groupVaccination = groupVaccinationList.get(position);
    vaccinationDrug.setText(groupVaccination.getVaccinationDrug());
    vaccinationDosage.setText(groupVaccination.getVaccinationDosage());
    vaccinationDate.setText(groupVaccination.getVaccinationDate());
    vaccinationID.setText(groupVaccination.getVaccinationID());
    vaccinationAdmin.setText(groupVaccination.getVaccinationAdmin());
    vaccinationGroupNumber.setText(groupVaccination.getVaccinationGroupNumber());
    vaccinationNotes.setText(groupVaccination.getVaccinationNotes());
allVaccinatedTrueFalse.setText(String.valueOf(Boolean groupVaccination.getAllVaccinated));

    return listView;
}
```

I have an error when I try to convert the `Boolean` to a `String` for allVaccinatedTrueFalse.setText. I'm assuming this way is wrong so any help would be appreciated! Let me know if there is any additonal information needed. Thank you!

Comment: `allVaccinatedTrueFalse.setText(groupVaccination.getAllVaccinated()?"true":"false");`   **try this**

Comment: `I have an error` which error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
allVaccinatedTrueFalse.setText(String.valueOf(Boolean groupVaccination.getAllVaccinated));
```

to

```
allVaccinatedTrueFalse.setText(String.valueOf(groupVaccination.getAllVaccinated()));
```